# Session Variables not working in header even though session_start is present

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have scoured the web (including Stack Overflow) for an answer to what is going on, but have had no luck :( I am trying to set up a user-based site that is done by sessions. My site is set up like so:

**index.php**

```
<?php include("header.php");

//some html stuff

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>"; 
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class='outer-nav'>
            <ul>
                <?php //navigation
                if (isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
                    echo '<li>' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '</li>';
                } else {
                    echo '<li>user_name does not exist</li>';
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r($_SESSION);
                    echo "</pre>";
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
```

The problem is that even though `session_start();` is IN the header file, the header file will not recognize the session variables, but the index file that includes the header (and does not have a separate `session_start();` iteself) is able to get session variables.

I have tried moving `session_start()` around and using `ob_start` and `ob_flush`, but have not found any way to be able to get session variables to be used in my header file (in the navigation bar specifically). What am I doing wrong??

[image: what is happening]

**EDIT**

Ok, so I think I figured out where the problem is originating. My index has an include before the header:

index.php

```
<?php include("admin/settings.php"); 
include("header.php");
```

settings.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
//just variable declarations here
```

header.php

```
//removed <?php session_start(); ?>
//see above for rest of code in header.php
```

When I change the code to this, now I'm getting the session variables in index body, but now I get `Notice: Undefined variable _SESSION in...` in the header. So now it's not even seeing the session at all... is this because it's an include?

**Addional Edit**

My session info from phpinfo():

[image: session info]

loggedin.php (where session variables are declared):

```
<?php

include_once("admin/settings.php");

$inputusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['user_name']);
$inputpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['user_pass']);

$sql = "SELECT user_id, user_name, user_pass, user_role, user_lastloggedin
    FROM user WHERE user_name = '$inputusername'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

if (!$result) { //query returned a mistake
    include_once($header);
    echo '<div class="full_page_content">';
    echo "<h1>Sign In</h1>";
    echo '<center>Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.</center>';
    //echo mysqli_error();
    include_once($footer);
    exit();
} elseif (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) { //check if user exists
    include_once($header);
    echo '<div class="full_page_content">';
    echo "<h1>Sign In</h1>";
    echo '<center>That username does not exist. Please check your spelling and try again.</center>';
    include_once($footer);
    exit();
} else { //user was found, continue login
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['user_name'];
        $pass = $row['user_pass'];
        $id = $row['user_id'];
        $role = $row['user_role'];
        $last = $row['user_lastloggedin'];
    }

    $errors = array();
    if (empty($inputpassword)) { //check if password field is empty
        $errors[] = '<center>The password field must not be empty</center>';
    } elseif (!password_verify($inputpassword, $pass)) {
        $errors[] = '<center>The password you entered was incorrect. Please check your spelling and try again.</center>';
    }


    if (!empty($errors)) { //if there are errors...
        include_once($header);
        echo '<div class="full_page_content">';
        echo "<h1>Sign In</h1>";
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
            echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        include_once($footer);
        exit();
    } else {
        //there are no errors, process the form
        $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $name;
        $_SESSION['user_role'] = $role;
        $now = time();

        if (strlen($last) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['first'] = true;
            header("Location: changepass.php");
        } else {
            mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE users SET user_lastloggedin='$now' WHERE user_id = '$id'");
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In header.php on line 1 you have</strike>

session start(); NOT session_start(); (Fixed)

Also, it seems you also forgot to close the PHP tags on line 1.

What happens if you echo the session variable before `session_start();` and what happens if you echo it after that (outside of any if statement)?

Alright, remove all `session_start();`, and then add a single `session_start();` into index.php.

**Make sure to have only 1 `session_start();` across all files you include.**

Answer (score -3):

try this instead `ob_start();`

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){

}
```

Comment: why try this? How does this help?

Comment: how you made $_SESSION['user_name'] maybe problem in there @Anna